# Select a MAX on Date column not working with empty table

Tags: sql, oracle

i am running the following query on one of my table which having a date column.

```
select max(date) from mydate
```

Problem is, when table is empty, then also its returning a row. I am using Oracle 11 .

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a valid behavior: aggregate functions usually return a `NULL` being applied to an empty set, and `COUNT(*)` returns `0`.

If you don't want a row if the table is empty, use this:

```
SELECT  MAX(date)
FROM    mydate
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is working.  It is just not working the way you think it should.  Always returning a result is [the documented behaviour for aggregating functions](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/functions001.htm#sthref1044).

```
SQL> select ts from t23;

TS
---------
25-APR-11
26-APR-11

SQL> select max(ts) from t23
  2  /

MAX(TS)
---------
26-APR-11

SQL> delete from t23
  2  /

2 rows deleted.

SQL> select max(ts) from t23
  2  /

MAX(TS)
---------


SQL>
```

However, if you really want an empty set and handle it accordingly you'll have to do something like this:

```
SQL> select max_ts from
  2      ( select max(ts) as max_ts from t23 )
  3  where max_ts is not null
  4  /

no rows selected

SQL>
```

---

Hmm, Quassnoi's solution is neater (less typing):

```
SQL> select max(ts) from t23
  2  having count(*) > 0
  3  /

no rows selected

SQL>
```

As Quassnoi points out, my solution will return an empty set even if the table has rows, provided no instance of the column TS is populated.  Q's solution would return a row with a NULL result under the same circumstances.  It depends on the business requirement as to which result is the right one.

Comment: `MAX(ts)` can also be `NULL` because of actual `NULL` values in `ts`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get ride of the `NULL` try:

```
CREATE TABLE my_date (
  the_date DATE
);

SELECT MAX(the_date) FROM my_date HAVING MAX(the_date) IS NOT NULL;
```

Cheers,

Comment: As Quassnoi points out, this will return an empty set if the table has rows but all the instances of THE_DATE are NULL.  This may not be the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Likely the query is returning one row with a null value.  That's the specified behavior of MAX.  This [link](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~wlam/compsci/sqlnulls) provides a decent overview of how NULL values are handled in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

select @maxPK = max(id) from #dd having count(id) > 0

this will work.